# Python: deleting one column, changing another one and writing the output on a file

Tags: python, input

I have my input text file in this form

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 10 11 12
```

I need to take it as input, delete the last column and multiply the third by a constant value, say 10 for example. So the final output should look like this:

```
1 2 30 
5 6 70
9 10 110
```

All this must be saved in a separate output file.
How to do this in Python?

Comment: either do it manually by reading each line and performing the operations or try using dataframe if possible

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd
with open('textfile.txt') as f:
    df = pd.read_csv(f, header=None, sep=' ')

df = df.drop(3, 1)  # 3 = column name, 1 indicates columns
df[2] = df[2] * 10 
df.to_csv(r'output.txt', header=None, index=None, sep=' ', mode='a')
```

Comment: it produces:  df = df.drop(3, 1)  # 3 = column name, 1 indicates columns     labels [3] not contained in axis

Comment: This error has something to do with the input file and the (sep = ' ') command. If this file is tab-separated you should use (sep = '\t')

Answer (score 1):

PS: only sample.

```
import csv
ff = open("output.csv","w") # added the line
csvwriter = csv.writer(ff)  # added the line
with open(file, "r") as logFile:
    reader = csv.reader(logFile,delimiter=" ")
    row = []
    for line in reader:
        col1 = lin[0]
        col2 = lin[1]
        col3 = int(lin[2]) * 10
        row = [col1,col2,col3]
        print row
        csvwriter.writerow(row)  # added the line
        del row[:]  # added the line
```

Comment: I cannot simply print I need to output to a file, how to do this?

Comment: @johnhenry added the functionality. encouraging you to practice over this.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
f = [map(int, i.strip('\n').split()) for i in open('thefile.txt')]

new_f = [i[:-1] for i in f]

new_f = [i[:-1]+[i[-1]*10] for i in new_f]

new_file = open('final_file.txt', 'a')

for i in new_f:
    new_file.write(' '.join(map(str, i))+"\n")

new_file.close()
```

Comment: How can I skip the last column when writing the output file?

Answer (score 1):

Just open the file as usual and strip it for newline and spaces and the you have a required list. REOPEN the same file in write mode to overwrite the existing content.then rewrite the first six values and next three by multiple that with that constant and use newlines as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Short implementation:

```
with open('filename') as f:
    inp = f.readlines()
inp = [ i.strip().split(' ')[:-1] for i in inp ]
out = '\n'.join([ ' '.join(i[:-1]) + ' ' + str(int(i[-1])*10) for i in inp ])
with open('filename','w') as f:
    f.write(out)
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried all the suggested answers, but I think that this is the most straightforward implementation. Some of the answers were not running correctly given my input file, or they were only partial answers to my question.

```
import numpy as np

factor= 10

a = np.loadtxt("inputfile.d")

b = a[:, :3]
b[:, 2] = factor*b[:, 2]
np.savetxt('outputfile.d',b)
```